# How do I run a specific program that requires a different version of Java without changing the default system version of Java?

Tags: server, java, openjdk, minecraft

I am using Ubuntu Server to host multiple Minecraft servers. For the latest versions of Minecraft, I need the latest version of Java; however, I would like to run a modded server as well and some of the mods are incompatible with the newest version of Java. How can I run the modded server using Java version 15 while running the other servers using the newest version? I am fairly new to Ubuntu Server so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just have multiple versions of Java installed?  If you need something complex, you could also use Docker if you wanted a more complex setup.

Comment: @cocomac I have multiple versions of Java installed; however, when you use the `java`command it defaults to the system default jdk does it not? I'm new to this so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Manually, you could use portable javas, such as `zulu`, `temurin`, `liberica`...etc, then have a folder that contains any version javas you need. Or using [java version manager](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba) to mange javas, or using [server management tool](https://github.com/MinecraftCube/MinecraftCubeDesktop) to add/specify java per server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you could run the java executable located in (I think) `/usr/lib/jvm/java-(version)-(vendor)/bin/java` the same way you'd just use the `java` link.

You'd still need to install the correct jvm version.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry if this is a stupid question. Can I run multiple versions by adding something to the command to start the server? Almost like adding a command-line argument? I'm sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: Instead of doing `java -jar minecraft.jar`, you'd just replace the `java` with the path of the java 8 executable, for example with OpenJDK 8, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java -jar minecraft.jar`

Comment: You could java anywhere you have downloaded it, not just `/us/lib/jvm`. Just run `/anywhere/bin/java -jar minecraft.jar`